How can I use a PHP-DI Container to pass mock objects while unit testing?
I have a controller that handles various cronjobs and I wanted to write unit tests for each function in the controller. The controller (lets call it TasksController) extends a base controller (let's call it BaseController). Previously, I was creating new objects of individual Task classes inside each concerned function, but since that's bad practice (ref1 ref2)that makes one's code hard to test, I used DI container to inject dependencies instead. A sample function from Task Controller would look like:
<?php

namespace Org\Controllers;

use DI\Container;
use Org\DbConnection;
use Org\Logger;
use Org\Tasks\SampleTask;

class TasksController extends BaseController
{
  public $container;

  // Task Objects:
  public $sampleTaskObject; 

  public function __construct(Container $container)
  {
    parent::__construct($container);
    $this->container = $container;
    // All objects for the task classes go below:
    $this->sampleTaskObject = $container->get(SampleTask::class);
  }

  function runSampleTaskObjectRun($request, $response, $args)
  {
    $this->sampleTaskObject->run();
    return $response->withStatus(200);
  }
}


The constructor for the base controller looks like:
class BaseController
{
  public $container;
  public $dbConn;
  public $logger;

  function __construct(Container $container)
  {
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->dbConn = $container->get(DbConnection::class);
    $this->logger = $container->get(Logger::class);
  }
}

In my unit tests,  I am able to run tests by directly doing:
$this->container = $this->createMock(Container::class);
$this->tasksController = new TasksController($this->container);
$sampleTaskMockObject = $this->createMock(SampleTask::class);
$this->taskController->sampleTaskObject = $sampleTaskMockObject

However, I would like to use my DI container to inject this mock dependency to my controller instead (ideally without changing the control flow of my controller). I have looked at a few references online that mock dependencies, but couldn't find one that does use container in a similar way.

You can mock the response from the $container->get method to return a mock object as well.
As you're using that method in two places, you can specify different parameters and return objects using returnValueMap
Try:
$sampleTaskMockObject = $this->createMock(SampleTask::class);
$loggerMockObject = $this->createMock(Logger::class);

$this->container = $this->createMock(Container::class);

$this->container
    ->method('get')
    ->will($this->returnValueMap([
        [DbConnection::class, $sampleTaskMockObject],
        [Logger::class, $loggerMockObject],
    ]));
    
$this->tasksController = new TasksController($this->container);

